# Creating A Randomised Array with a Single Pre-defined Choice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm creating a program that will ask a question and give 5 choices for answers.
One is pre-defined and is correct, the others I want to be random selections from a bank of answers and the entire array is to be shuffled too.

I've written something, but it has some inconsistencies.
For one, sometimes the pre-defined choice appears twice in the list (it appears to skip over my `if` check).
Another is that sometimes, the editor crashes when I run it.
I use `for in` loops and I'm worried the crash is caused by a never-ending loop.

Here's my code:

```
private var numberOfComponents:int;
private var maxComponents:int = 5;

//numberOfComponents returns the length property of my 'components' answer bank

componentsSelection = buildComponentSelectionList(0); //0 is the index of my correct answer

function buildComponentSelectionList(correctItemIndex){
    var theArray:Array = new Array();
    var indicesOfSelection:Array = getIndicesByIncluding(correctItemIndex);
    Debug.Log(indicesOfSelection);
    for (var i=0;i<indicesOfSelection.length;i++)
        theArray.Push(components[indicesOfSelection[i]]);
    return theArray;
}
function getIndicesByIncluding(correctItem){
    var indicesArray:Array = new Array();
    var numberOfChoices = maxComponents-1;  
    for(var i=0;i<numberOfChoices;i++){
        var number = Mathf.Round(Random.value*(numberOfComponents-1));
        addToRandomNumberSelection(indicesArray, number,correctItem);
    }   
    indicesArray.Push(correctItem);
    RandomizeArray(indicesArray);                                                                   
    return indicesArray;
}
function addToRandomNumberSelection(indicesArray:Array,number,correctItem){
    if(indicesArray.length == 0){
        indicesArray.Push(number);
    } else {    
        var doesntExist = true;
        for(var i=0;i<indicesArray.length;i++){
            if(indicesArray[i] == correctItem)
                doesntExist = false;
            if (indicesArray[i] == number)
                doesntExist = false;        
        }
        if(doesntExist) {
            indicesArray.Push(number);  
        } else {
            addToRandomNumberSelection(indicesArray, Mathf.Round(Random.value*(numberOfComponents-1)),correctItem);
        } 
    }
}
function RandomizeArray(arr : Array)
{
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var r = Random.Range(0,i);
        var tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
}
```

The editor is Unity3D, and the code is a version of JavaScript; I think my error is a logic one, rather than a syntactical one.

I feel I've been staring at this code for too long now and I'm missing something obvious.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well for starters don't use `for ... in` loops for numerically-indexed arrays. Use an index variable.

Comment: Okay, I've converted these to indexed. I'm still getting the crash, but no more duplicates!

Comment: To simplify your script somewhat, use `if (indecesArray.indexOf(number) < 0)` to determine that an item doesn't exist. When you say sometimes the editor crashes, does it give you any indication of why? Could it be that your recursive method call is getting out of hand? (I.e., you're always getting a `doesntExist` value of `false`). Actually, now that I look at it, won't that always be the case if you have `correctItem` in the array?

Comment: correctItem isn't added to the array until after the 4 random indices are generated. I'll take a look at your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the options and determine the probability that it should be included, then shuffle the included options:

```
function getRandomOptions(allOptions, correctIndex, count){
  var result = [allOptions[correctIndex]];
  count--;
  var left = allOptions.length;
  for (var i = 0; count > 0; i++) {
    if (i != correctIndex && Math.floor(Math.random() * left) < count) {
      result.push(allOptions[i]);
      count--;
    }
    left--;
  }
  shuffleArray(result);
  return result;
}

function shuffleArray(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    var tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/wXsjz/